# Height Auto Not Working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using `bootstrap` and basic CSS on my app and for some reason the `height-auto` on a div isn't working.  The height is shown as 0 even though there is text in the div.  Here's my html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="outlined-div">
    <h2 class="text-center col-xs-12" style="color: red">Men are not born knowing how&nbsp;to&nbsp;barbecue.</h2>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <h4>Good luck explaining this to your buddies.</h4>
      <h4>All men are capable. Few are properly trained.</h4>
      <h4>Instead, we undergo years of trial and error, suffering through snide comments from our buddies and smug looks from our fathers-in-law. This ends now.</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
      <h4>While men don’t ask for directions (see the man code), it’s only right that we share hints, hacks, and other help with our fellow brothers.</h4>
      <h4>Give them a leg up in impressing others with our stellar barbecuemanship.</h4>
      <h2 style="color: red">Grill on, brothers.</h2>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- outlined-div -->
</div> <!-- container -->
```

Here's my css for `outlined-div`:

```
.outlined-div {
  background-color: white;
  border: solid medium red;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  height: auto !important;
}
```

And here's how it's showing up:

[image]

If I put in a fixed height (e.g. `height: 10px`) the red line expands into a box 10px high.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the class `clearfix` to your  `outlined-div`

This will clear the floats added by Bootstrap to create the column layout.

To learn more about clearfixes, read this question: [What is a clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)